# Using ASP.NET identity on multiple applications for 2 websites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am going to develop 2 websites site1.com, site2.com and mobile APIs api.com
site1.com for admin
site2.com for portal
Api.com for mobile

**So, shall i use the same identity for all of them or use one identity for admin site and one for portal and mobile?**

Another Question
if i am going to deploy a WebAPI App under MVC App,and i will authenticate the users on mvc app, **how can i use the same authenticate and authorization for WebAPI and MVC together to avoid 401 response for API calls**

Comment: "So, shall i use the same identity for all of them or use one identity for admin site and one for portal and mobile" ...that depends on how you want it to work. What do you anticipate would be the problem with using a single identity provider (since that would clearly be simpler)? As long as you set permissions correctly, it should not be an issue. We can't really answer your question definitively without understanding your specific concerns.

Comment: For the second question, it sounds like you are looking for a single-sign-on (SSO) setup, using a shared identity provider, possibly using some sort of federation.

Comment: Development will be on multiple releases but in this case identity will be created in 1st release so shall i be able to change and extend the existing identity at any release after that. 
And if i want to deploy an API under this site without implementing SSO